# Html5 Canvas to Server via vb.net & Ajax

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, html5-canvas

I am trying to implement a piece of code I found on the net to upload some drawings on an html5 canvas so that I can attached the image to an email.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Send the canvas image to the server.
        $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnSave').live('click', function () {

            var image = document.getElementById("tools_sketch").toDataURL();
            image = image.replace('data:image/png;base64,', '');
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'upload.aspx/UploadImage',
                data: '{ "imageData" : "' + image + '" }',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (msg) {
                    alert('Image sent!');
                }, 
                error: function (msg2) {
                    alert('Image problem!' + msg2.toString());
                 }

            });
         });

     });


        </script>
```

***upload.aspx***

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="upload.aspx.vb" Inherits="CanvasToServer._upload" %>
```

***upload.aspx.vb***

Imports System.IO
Namespace CanvasToServer
    Partial Class _upload
        Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

        Public Shared Sub UploadImage(ByVal imageData As String)

```
        Dim fs As New FileStream("C:\uploaded\image.png", FileMode.Create)
        Dim bw As New BinaryWriter(fs)
        Dim data As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(imageData)

        bw.Write(data)
        bw.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

End Namespace

The  line is causing a compilation error "Attribute specifier is not a complete statement. Use a line continuation to apply the attribute to the following statement."  If I remove that line the code compiles but the canvas image still does not upload to the server.  I am running this code on localhost and the folder c:\uploaded does exist on my machine.